# Javascript in code behind after clientclick and vice versa

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0, telerik

Right now I have a radgrid that is filled with checkboxes. If I click on a check box it calls my code behind checkchanged. In check changed it checks and see if that item is active if its not it throws an alert. I want to change that alert to a confirm but the radajaxpanel doesn't appear to have a method for confirm so I figure I need to create one in javascript and call it in the code behind.

What I have now

```
        else
        {
            RadAjaxPanel1.Alert("The event you selected is currently In-Active");
        }
```

So I assume I would need to change that to a call of the javascript or something similar to call for a confirm and then return the response in the codebehind to either continue or stop.

EDIT: If this helps maybe what I am trying to explain is. On codebehind trigger a javascript method to run and return a value for my codebehind to evaluate and continue or stop running.

EDIT 2:Or what I want to change is on clientclick it calls the javascript and if the javascript return Yes then it calls the codebehind. Maybe that is more likely and possible.

Comment: If this helps maybe what I am trying to explain is. On codebehind trigger a javascript method to run and return a value for my codebehind to evaluate and continue or stop running.

Comment: Or what I want to change is on clientclick it calls the javascript and if the javascript return Yes then it calls the codebehind. Maybe that is more likely and possible.